# QAction shortcut keys not working

Tags: qt, qtablewidget

i am adding QAction to QTableWidget as

```
m_pCutAction = new QAction( "Cut",this );
    m_pCutAction->setIcon(QIcon(":/Img/cut.png"));
    m_pCutAction->setShortcut(Qt::CTRL + Qt::Key_X);
 connect(m_pCutAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(cut()));

 m_pCopyAction = new QAction( "Copy",this );
    m_pCopyAction->setIcon(QIcon(":/Img/copy.png"));
    m_pCopyAction->setShortcut(Qt::CTRL + Qt::Key_C);
```

and in contextMenu

```
void contextMenuEvent(QContextMenuEvent *event)
{
QScopedPointer<QMenu>menu(new QMenu());
    menu->addAction(m_pCutAction);
    menu->addAction(m_pCopyAction);
    menu->addAction(m_pPasteAction);
    menu->exec(event->globalPos());
 QTableWidget::contextMenuEvent(event);
}
```

but the action is not executing for Ctrl + X but it is executing from Ctrl +C. Copy operation i can perform but Cut operation i cant perform using keys.

i tried

> m_pCutAction ->setShortcut(QKeySequence::Cut);

but this is also not helping me. same for paste and delete. only Copy operation i can do.

Comment: are you sure the other shortcuts do not get grabbed by the `parent()` widget? and so on (`parent()->parent()`). look at `QWidget::grabKeyboard()`

Comment: thanks bibi for the reply. but im not getting it. why only for ctrl+C is working and rest is not working. i guess it will work only in qt 4+ version.

Comment: im using new QShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt::CTRL + Qt::Key_X),
                     this, SLOT(cut())); option right now . but still not able to figure out the problem

Comment: I was just wondering if some these shortcuts are already defined in parent (or ancestor!) they might get filtered and cannot reach your widget.

Comment: your point makes sense .but im not doing anything on Parent widget. it is just a QWidget. EntryMainWidget::EntryMainWidget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent)
{
    m_pTableWidget = new TableWidget(this);

    QVBoxLayout *mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
    mainLayout->addWidget(m_pTableWidget);

    this->setLayout(mainLayout);
}

Comment: ok, did you try to use the `m_pTableWidget->grabKeyboard()` ?

Comment: thanks bibi . yes i tried but in vain .

Comment: what about reimplementing the `void keyPressEvent (QKeyEvent *);` ?

Comment: im using new QShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt::CTRL + Qt::Key_X), this, SLOT(cut()));  it is working .

Comment: and keypress event also not giving the keys event for Ctrt+x and Ctrl+V . im surprised.